# android videoview play, pause and stop video

Tags: android

Hello I would like to have play, pause and stop for my videoview, but can't seem to do that. Take a look at the code below:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setContentView(R.layout.iworkout);
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.exercises32);

    vv = (VideoView) findViewById (R.id.vv_Exercise);
    play = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btWorkOutPlay);
    pause = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btWorkOutPause);
    stop = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btWorkOutStop);



}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btWorkOutPlay:
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.exercise1);
        vv.start();
        vv.setVideoURI(uri);
        break;
    case R.id.btWorkOutPause:
        vv.pause();
        break;
    case R.id.btWorkOutStop:
        vv.stopPlayback();
        break;
    }

} // end of onClick method
```

If anyone knows how to do it, I'll appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MediaController` with `VideoView`:

```
....
MediaController mc= new MediaController();
Videoview.setMediaController(mc);
....
```

Comment: case R.id.btWorkOutPlay:
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.exercise1);
      MediaController nc = new MediaController(this); 
      vv.setMediaController(nc); 
   
   vv.start();
   vv.setVideoURI(uri);
   break;